# How can I specify quotes(" ") in my string text in Python?

Tags: python, command-line, syntax-error

The command I want to run from my python script is:

```
tool-manager-cli -a "somexml.xml" -c "another.xml"
```

My python code is:

```
command1 = """ tool-manager-cli -a "somexml.xml" -c "another.xml" """
subprocess.Popen(command1)
```

However when I run my py script, I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax as my error for this line.

How can I specify quotes(" ") in my string text without closing it or invalid syntax?

Comment: Use single quotes `'` on the outside instead. Or escape your double quotes with blackslashes `\"`.

Comment: Adding onto Loocid you can also specify that your string is rawtext by putting an r in front of the string, which will escape all the quotes inside

Comment: @Loocid putting single quotes dosent seem to work when I have 2 file paths using " ".  Can you show me what you eman with backslashes in my code?

Comment: @Yubi `command1 = 'tool-manager-cli -a "somexml.xml" -c "another.xml"'`

Comment: @Loocid I tried that, does not work, still getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax. What do you mean by the backslashes?

Comment: @Yubi `command1 =  "tool-manager-cli -a \"somexml.xml\" -c \"another.xml\""` However theres no reason the single quotes wouldnt work, they work fine for me. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry I had another syntax error, my bad. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Voting to close as typo based on OP's last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using single quotes to differentiate like so

```
command1 = """ tool-manager-cli -a 'somexml.xml' -c 'another.xml' """
```

Comment: It wont work, getting OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect error...the xml file path need to be in double quotes.

Comment: So this is a quick guess, ill look further into the issue and come back, but try replacing the single comma with &quot;
so &quot;another.xml&quot;

Comment: My bad I had another syntax error while using the single quotes, my bad. It works now thanks :)

Comment: There's no reason whatsoever why &quot; should or could work in this context. This is not HTML, &quot; will always be interpreted as just 6 normal characters, not as the quotation mark. The escape sequences in python strings are listed here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals - \" or \x34 or using it unescaped if the string is surrounded with singlequotes would all work.

Comment: the original answer I went with was single quotes, looked through previous works to see what might apply because I was stepping away for a minute.  The single quote solution worked and i switched it back

Answer (score 0):

You can use format method to structure your command:

```
command1= "{} {} {} {} {}".format("tool-managel-cli","-a", "somexml.xml","-c","another.xml")
subprocess.Popen(command1)
```

You can also concat by `+` , but its tedious ofcourse

```
command1 ="tool-manager-cli"+" -a"+ " somexml.xml" + " -c "+" another.xml"
```